# Can't get scrolltop to work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a fiddle to show what is happening.

I am using jquery to fade in a link to the top of the page when the user is scrolling down.

I can get it to work on jsfiddle if I place the code in the javascript window, but if I put it in script tags where my $( window ).load(function() is in the HTML window, it doesn't work at all. Does anybody know why?

```
$('#slide').bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
        $("#top").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("#top").stop().fadeOut();
    }
});

$('#top').on("click",function(){
      $('#slide').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
});
```

here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8130fdhm/2/

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Is your script tag after you load jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in a script tag just before the body end tag. I have updated the jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/8130fdhm/3/

```
....
<script>

$('#slide').bind("scroll", function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
    $("#top").fadeIn();
} else {
    $("#top").stop().fadeOut();
}
});

$('#top').on("click",function(){
  $('#slide').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Ahhhhh, I'm guessing it's because the elements don't exist yet if it's running it in the head? Thank you Praveen! =)